# Как обновлять браузер в obs используя python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, браузер, streaming

Есть источник(браузер) он отображает сайт, но при изменении сайта он так и остается на том же месте.
хочу что-бы источник раз в 20 секунд обновлялся. Как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Врятли python здесь как то поможет. Если поставить галочку в настройках, сайт будет  обновляться при активации-деактивации окна (нажатие на глаз), но сделать это автоматически средствами ОБСа нельзя. Хотя возможно существуют плагины, которые расширяют работу браузера в обсе. Таковых я не нашел.
Если есть отдельный комп, который отвечает за стрим, можно на нем поставить скриптик на pyautogui который будет раз в 20 сек нажимать на глазик, обновляя окно ))

Comment: Спасибо, я понял как это сделать.Смотри я знаю как выключать и включать глазик у ресурса поэтому я просто поставлю таймер который будет глазик вкл/выкл и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Полно расширений для хрома выполняющих такую функцию, например https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh-plus-arp/hgeljhfekpckiiplhkigfehkdpldcggm

"Auto Refresh Plus - ARP"

Comment: А при чём тут хром, если речь про OBS?